# How to access Images and 3D object from android internal Storage using Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to access the storage folder from android internal storage, to load the images and 3d objects into the Unity scene. I already have the folder inside the device but for now, I don't know how to access the folder and how to load the object.. and I still new to Unity and C#. I will be appreciated it if someone can guide me or share the code with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- [For phone gallery access](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/native-gallery-for-android-ios-112630)
- [For asset loading](https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/BetterStreamingAssets)

I am not an expert so I am not explain better than the resources on the pages referred.